# Web service request takes a very long time

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx

I am using an asmx web service to communicate
from one web server to another, both are on localhost. When the response is large (~20 MB)
It takes a very long time (~3 minutes) to receive it.

It is not a networking issues, I tested similar calls on stand alone process hosting similar web functions -  and it took a few seconds.
I tried compressing the data so in fact only a byte array is passed , but it also didn't help.

My server config is:

```
<system.web>
   ...
    <compilation defaultLanguage="vb" debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

  ...
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="1380" name=".ASPXAUTH" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="default.aspx" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
      <!-- Allow all users -->
      <!--  <allow     users="[comma separated list of users]"
                             roles="[comma separated list of roles]"/>
                  <deny      users="[comma separated list of users]"
                             roles="[comma separated list of roles]"/>
            -->
    </authorization>
  ...
    <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="525600" />

  ...

    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" maxRequestLength="102400" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" />
    <!-- <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/> -->
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
  </system.web>
```

Any ideas on what may be causing this delay?

Comment: What does a profile (both client and server) show is taking the time?

Comment: I can't see what it causing the delay, how can I perform such a profile?

Comment: That depends on your tools. Eg. recent VS of sufficient edition (eg. is in Premium) include a profiler.

Comment: I have VS2012, In debug I see that web method returns the data on the server side (external code) and in the client I'm stuck waiting for the data. Is there a better profiler in VS2012 I can use? Thanks.

Comment: Check out the `Analyze` menu for the profiler. A debugger is *not* a profiler.

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you suggeted, but CPU / memory profiling don't help me, the problem is in externl code and the profiler doesn't show it. For some reason when I use WCF endpoint to point to the same method (basic HTTP binding) the performance is MUCH better.

Comment: You might need to use a lower level/more powerful tool like Windows Performance Toolkit: Channel9's [Defrag Tools](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools) have covered it in detail. For third party components you just need symbols (they might provide them if asked to help diagnose your problems with their component).